# MacOS Ventura freezes/crashes when i plug in my Arduino Nano Clone

Tags: arduino-nano, mac-os, clones

I'm using a MacBook Pro 2013 Late with OpenCore Patcher. Currently Ventura 13.3.1 is installed. Before this version was installed, I had no problem using arduino on my MacOS computer. But right now, when I plug in my Arduino Nano Clone, the computer suddenly freezes and does not respond to any interaction. I have to press and hold the power button to restart the computer.

I tried to plug in another board called NodeMCU which has CH340 chip likewise I did with the arduino, same trouble happened again. So at that point I was guessing it was a CH340 driver problem or something about it. To test my theory, I plugged in my Raspberry Pi Pico and it worked perfectly. So it's probably CH340 chip problem but I could not find any solution in web. May there is a system integrity problem with OpenCore which the version is not compatible with the current operation system version.

If anyone can help me with this issue I'd be really appreciated, since I have a project which must be completed within 3 weeks.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/adrianmihalko/ch340g-ch34g-ch34x-mac-os-x-driver , and this: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ch340-drivers/all#mac-osx

Comment: Clone Arduino has a history of doing that. Check here:
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/macbook-keeps-crashing-when-i-plug-in-ch340-arduino/440584